# Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

I'm getting a 400 Requested failed with status code 400 Error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I have the correct JWT. Below is my App.js file and a snippet of the error in console.log. Many thanks in advance.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Styled from 'styled-components';

const  Wrapper = Styled.div `
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
`;

function App() {
  const [clanData, setClanData] = useState([]);
  const jwt = "<MY API TOKEN HERE>";
  const clanTag = "%23LPPLR8YL";
  const clanUrl = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/clans/${ clanTag }`;

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios
      .get(clanUrl, {
        headers:
        { authorization: `Bearer ${ jwt }`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setClanData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [clanData]);
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      Still Not A Pro
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppPHZ.png]

Comment: You probably do not need `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` as a header because 1) you aren't sending any data as it is a GET 2) axios requests default to application/json when there is a body

Comment: Does that look like the correct URL to you?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Originally I didn't have it there. But one of the TLs from my class suggested it. But I get the same code in the image with or without 'Content-Type': 'application/json' there'

Comment: @AluanHaddad The original link I have is https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/clans/${ clanTag } however when I do that i get a CORS error hence why I tried the https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com route

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that was a thing. I should have looked at the URL more closely. Anyway, you need to debug this sever side.

Comment: is `%` a valid `clanTag`? The error has the url `/clans/%`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes i don't know why but the API changes "#" to "%23"

Comment: It is [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) special characters

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Whats so weird is that it works in Postman